# MLFlow - count number of runs given an experiment name

Tags: python, mlflow

Is there a way count number of runs given an experiment name? I'm using python.
E.g. I have an experiment name: "Test" and I wish to get the number of runs somehow like this, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation:

```
experiment_name = "test"
count = mlflow.get_number_of_runs(experiment_name)
print(f'There are {count} runs in {experiment_name}')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html#mlflow.client.MlflowClient.list_run_infos and then do a len(). Will need to account for paging results.

Also see: https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-tools/blob/master/mlflow_tools/common/search_runs_iterator.py